# Grails - Frequent JVM crash

Tags: grails, groovy, jvm-crash

I am working on a fairly large grails project with over a 100 domain classes.
Recently we upgraded to grails 2.4.4 and I am seeing frequent jvm crash since then, its like, jvm will crash two out of five times, when i do a clean compile.

Environment
- Windows 7 64 bit
- JDK - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
- Grails 2.4.4

Crash report

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005da6959b, pid=6788, tid=5404

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_71-b14) (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x2959b]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 F:\work\odesk\playground\9ci\rcm\hs_err_pid6788.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Here's the crash report log file https://gist.github.com/snimavat/92ea290047fc0ac36989

Any idea what's going wrong ?

Comment: Did you try it with Java8?

Comment: No, but anyway, i have to use java7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your computer's memory is not corrupted you found a JVM C2 compiler bug - congratulations!

If jdk8 is no option try jdk7u60, since we know that this version works reasonably well. u65 has issues, so I cannot suggest that one.

Comment: Computer Memory is good, and i have 8gigs, i will report the bug